# Return dictionary items if 3 fields sum to a certain number

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of students and their grades, and I need to return students who

- Have `TP01`, `TP02`, and `TP03` sum higher than 30

Here is a mock dict to work with:

```
{'Name': ['Colin', 'Doyon', 'Tremblay', 'Audry', 'Gamelin', 'Dagenais', 'Legault',
  'Larochelle', 'Gagnon', 'Simard'], 
'FirstName': ['Jonas', 'Elisabeth', 'Françcois', 'Francine', 'Geneviève',
  'Robert', 'Maxime', 'Pierre', 'Emilie', 'Martine'],
 'TP01': ['7', '9.5', '8', '5', '6', '8', '10', '3', '7', '8'],
 'TP02': ['12', '14', '12', '13', '10', '12', '14', '11', '10', '15'],
 'TP03': ['11', '12', '11', '10', '10', '13', '12', '6', '7', '14'],
 'EXAMEN_INTRA': ['22', '26', '20', '22', '20', '23', '27', '15', '13', '28'],
 'EXAMEN_FINAL': ['28', '20', '22', '15', '14', '22', '25', '14', '14', '27']}
```

I can unfortunately not use any libraries.

**What I have tried:**

```
sums = list()
for tp1, tp2, tp3 in zip(dict_etudiants['TP01'], dict_etudiants['TP02'], dict_etudiants['TP03']):
    sums.append(sum((float(tp1), float(tp2), float(tp3)))) # but then it leads nowhere
```

Comment: do you know now to use `"if"` ? `if sum(...) > 30: ...`

Comment: I'm sorry you're having a bad day

Comment: and you would have to `zip()` other information if you what to get student. `zip(dict_etudiants['Name'], dict_etudiants['TP01'], ....)`

Comment: I'm aware of that. I have tried many solutions, and that happened to be the last. I had to provide _some_ code so obviously I didn't give something that came close to work.

Comment: as for me the worst thing is your data structure - you keep in separated list names, firstnames, etc. You should keep information about single student in sinlge dictionary or list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem is your data structure - you keep values in separated lists but all information about single student should be in single dictionary or list and then it would be much easier.

Something like this:

```
studends = [
  {'Name': 'Colin', 'FirstName': 'Jonas', 'TP01': '7', 'TP02': '12', 'TP03': '11', 'EXAMEN_INTRA': '22', 'EXAMEN_FINAL': '28'},
  {'Name': 'Doyon', 'FirstName': 'Elisabeth', ....},
  ...
]
```

---

This code get all studends with `sum > 30` but it returns every student in separate list - so if you need your original structure then you will have to convert result.

```
dict_etudiants = {
    'Name': ['Colin', 'Doyon', 'Tremblay', 'Audry', 'Gamelin', 'Dagenais', 'Legault',
  'Larochelle', 'Gagnon', 'Simard'], 
    'FirstName': ['Jonas', 'Elisabeth', 'Françcois', 'Francine', 'Geneviève',
  'Robert', 'Maxime', 'Pierre', 'Emilie', 'Martine'],
     'TP01': ['7', '9.5', '8', '5', '6', '8', '10', '3', '7', '8'],
     'TP02': ['12', '14', '12', '13', '10', '12', '14', '11', '10', '15'],
     'TP03': ['11', '12', '11', '10', '10', '13', '12', '6', '7', '14'],
     'EXAMEN_INTRA': ['22', '26', '20', '22', '20', '23', '27', '15', '13', '28'],
     'EXAMEN_FINAL': ['28', '20', '22', '15', '14', '22', '25', '14', '14', '27']
}


students = list()
for tp1, tp2, tp3, name, firstname, examen_intra, examen_final in zip(dict_etudiants['TP01'], dict_etudiants['TP02'], dict_etudiants['TP03'],
                         dict_etudiants['Name'], dict_etudiants['FirstName'], dict_etudiants['EXAMEN_INTRA'], dict_etudiants['EXAMEN_FINAL']):
    if sum((float(tp1), float(tp2), float(tp3))) > 30:
        students.append([name, firstname, tp1, tp2, tp3, examen_intra, examen_final])

print(students)
```

Result

```
[
  ['Doyon', 'Elisabeth', '9.5', '14', '12', '26', '20'],
  ['Tremblay', 'Françcois', '8', '12', '11', '20', '22'], 
  ['Dagenais', 'Robert', '8', '12', '13', '23', '22'], 
  ['Legault', 'Maxime', '10', '14', '12', '27', '25'], 
  ['Simard', 'Martine', '8', '15', '14', '28', '27']
]
```

---

**EDIT:** I released that you could convert it to `pandas.DataFrame` and then it is easy to search students.

```
result = df[ df['TP01'] + df['TP02'] + df['TP03'] > 30 ]
```

Full code

```
dict_etudiants = {
    'Name': ['Colin', 'Doyon', 'Tremblay', 'Audry', 'Gamelin', 'Dagenais', 'Legault',
  'Larochelle', 'Gagnon', 'Simard'], 
    'FirstName': ['Jonas', 'Elisabeth', 'Françcois', 'Francine', 'Geneviève',
  'Robert', 'Maxime', 'Pierre', 'Emilie', 'Martine'],
     'TP01': ['7', '9.5', '8', '5', '6', '8', '10', '3', '7', '8'],
     'TP02': ['12', '14', '12', '13', '10', '12', '14', '11', '10', '15'],
     'TP03': ['11', '12', '11', '10', '10', '13', '12', '6', '7', '14'],
     'EXAMEN_INTRA': ['22', '26', '20', '22', '20', '23', '27', '15', '13', '28'],
     'EXAMEN_FINAL': ['28', '20', '22', '15', '14', '22', '25', '14', '14', '27']
}

import pandas as pd
import pprint

# create DateFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_etudiants)

# convert strings to float
df['TP01'] = df['TP01'].astype(float)
df['TP02'] = df['TP02'].astype(float)
df['TP03'] = df['TP03'].astype(float)

# search students
result = df[ df['TP01'] + df['TP02'] + df['TP03'] > 30 ]

# convert back to dictionary
dict_etudiants_selected = result.to_dict(orient='list')

print('\n--- DataFrame ---\n')
print(result)

print('\n--- dict ---\n')
pprint.pprint(dict_etudiants_selected)
```

Result

```
--- DataFrame ---

       Name  FirstName  TP01  TP02  TP03 EXAMEN_INTRA EXAMEN_FINAL
1     Doyon  Elisabeth   9.5  14.0  12.0           26           20
2  Tremblay  Françcois   8.0  12.0  11.0           20           22
5  Dagenais     Robert   8.0  12.0  13.0           23           22
6   Legault     Maxime  10.0  14.0  12.0           27           25
9    Simard    Martine   8.0  15.0  14.0           28           27

--- dict ---

{'EXAMEN_FINAL': ['20', '22', '22', '25', '27'],
 'EXAMEN_INTRA': ['26', '20', '23', '27', '28'],
 'FirstName': ['Elisabeth', 'Françcois', 'Robert', 'Maxime', 'Martine'],
 'Name': ['Doyon', 'Tremblay', 'Dagenais', 'Legault', 'Simard'],
 'TP01': [9.5, 8.0, 8.0, 10.0, 8.0],
 'TP02': [14.0, 12.0, 12.0, 14.0, 15.0],
 'TP03': [12.0, 11.0, 13.0, 12.0, 14.0]}
```

Comment: You're completely right. The dictionary format is the problem. Python just isn't made for dealing with such a structure.

Comment: I released you could convert it to `pandas.DataFrame` and then it is easy. See new code in answer.